# Usage of retina images and setting an UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

It is the first time that I need to use images with the name formats of like: `@2x and -568h@2x` But I do not understand when the `-568@2x` is used. This should be for iPhone 5 and up but, the image is not used on my iPhone 5S when testing.

I tried very hard searching for this problem, but I cannot find it.

**Problem:**
Only the @2x image is used on all devices, and the -568@2x is ignored totally. So there is a gap above my image on screen while I have set the UIImageView in Storyboard to fill the whole screen. So in my understanding, with the setImage it would look first in the Project folder, and then to the Asset Catalog. But still it does not take the `-568@2x` image and always take the @2x image.

I have also set the auto layout right for the UIImageView so it would fit top, bottom, left, right.

**Code/Screen:**

So I have 2 images in my Project folder as you can see on the image:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLvsE.png)

Here is the gap on top:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF8Ha.png)

And then in my code I use this code for setting the image on my Outlet:

```
[[self image] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstLaunch"]];
```

So what could be the problem? Am I totally wrong how the Automatic image names thingy is working?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless they changed it recently, the 568 name only works for the launch image.  Other images you have to load yourself after checking the UIScreen bounds to see what device you're on.

Comment: Ow really, I tough that this was made for this sort of situations. So this works only for LaunchImages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    self.view.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstLaunch@R4"].CGImage;
} else {
    self.view.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstLaunch@2x"].CGImage;
}
```